# Visual Studio Build Error: "Being in the internet or restricted zone"

Tags: c#

I wanted to build my solution of my app, however this error popped out:

```
Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you download the project, or part of it, from the internet?

If so, you might have to unblock the file(s) first.  Select the file(s) in windows explorer, right click, select properties, and on the "General" tab you will see this.

[image: Unblock file]

You have to select "Unblock" for each of the files.

**Be careful that you know what you have downloaded and that it comes from a trusted source and have scanned the files for viruses etc.**